# shell - wrapping variables in quotes

Tags: shell, unix

Can someone please explain me what is the use of wrapping variables in quotes in shell scripting.
I know that it will be helpful to bind two or more strings but what is the purpose if I have a single string/integer.

```
X=0
while [ -n "$X" ]
do
   echo "Enter some text (RETURN to quit)"
   read X
   if [ -n "$X" ]; then
      echo "You said: $X"
   fi
done
```

If I don't keep $X in quotes in line 2, the script is not terminating even after I press RETURN.

Comment: **-n** flag expects **STRING** type parameter to check length of string.
[link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: yes, but what does quotes have to do with it?

Comment: Without quotes, the shell performs _word splitting_ and _pathname expansion_ and these can have a wide variety of surprising effects.  Doubles quotes suppresses both of these expansions.

Answer (score 1):

Run the script in debug mode to see the difference regarding how the condition is interpreted.

```
bash -x ${shell_file}
```

1. When quotes are mentioned - `+ '[' -n '' ']'`
2. When quotes are not mentioned - `+ '[' -n ']'` (which is always `true`)

`X` will be empty when `RETURN` key is pressed, but interpreter will consider only when it is quoted.